# Looking for articles on automated deployment pros/cons

Tags: deployment, build-automation

currently my team is working on a web-based service which has a very manual deployment process. I'd like to convince my management team to consider spending the engineering effort to bake automated deployment into our engineering practice. Can anyone suggest articles that help me make this argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html) by Martin Fowler (ThoughtWorks) talks mainly about continuous integration, but touches on the benefits of automated deployment further down the article.

"How automated deployment can reduce cost, risk and complexity" article [here](http://wikis.sun.com/download/attachments/80281962/drolshammer.pdf?version=2) looks quite comprehensive too

Answer (score 1):

[Continuous Delivery](http://continuousdelivery.com/) is an entire book on the benefits of (and how to) automating deployment throughout your entire development/test/production cycle. This has become my bible.

Answer (score 0):

A quick readover on this forum discussion: (link at bottom) brings up some good advantages/disadvantages to automatic deployment. Hope it helps!

http://www.cmcrossroads.com/component/option,com_fireboard/Itemid,593/func,view/catid,4/id,96779/

I don't know why the link doesnt work in url mode...

Comment: Hopefully fixed the link, if it continues not to work just copy pasta it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple decent articles I've read on the topic:

[How I came to value build and deployment tools](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/content/view/12247/120/) (M. Sayko on CMCrossroads)

[Continuous Deployment](http://timothyfitz.wordpress.com/2009/02/10/continuous-deployment-at-imvu-doing-the-impossible-fifty-times-a-day/) (Timothy Fitz of IMVU via Wordpress)